# How to use & after const string

Tags: c++, class, virtual, abstract

```
virtual const string & getType() const = 0;
```

What does `&` mean after `const string`? I am a newbie and trying to understand how basic c++ works.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: Not a comprehensive as his books, but a decent place to decide whether or not you should get one of his books: https://isocpp.org/tour

Answer (score 2):

It's a pure virtual function that returns a reference to a `const string`.  The ampersand in this usage means the function returns a *reference* to a string, rather than the string itself.  In this case it's a way to avoid passing an arbitrarily large object as the return value from a function - the compiler just generates code that returns an opaque reference to an existing string, and the caller can use it as if it were the original string.